# правильно ли поделено предложение на предикативные единица?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Я так была отуманена этою, внезапно возбужденною/, как мне казалось, любовью ко мне во всех посторонних, этим воздухом изящества, удовольствий и новизны/, которым я дышала здесь в первый раз/, так вдруг исчезло здесь его, подавлявшее меня, моральное влияние/, так приятно мне было в этом мире не только сравняться с ним/, но стать выше его/, и за то любить его еще больше и самостоятельнее/, чем прежде/, что я не могла понять/, что неприятного он мог видеть для меня в светской жизни/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 предикативных единиц, т.е. простых предложений:

[Я так была отуманена этою, внезапно возбужденною, как мне казалось, любовью ко мне во всех посторонних, этим воздухом изящества, удовольствий и новизны],( которым я дышала здесь в первый раз), [так вдруг исчезло здесь его, подавлявшее меня, моральное влияние], [так приятно мне было в этом мире не только сравняться с ним, но стать выше его, и за то любить его еще больше и самостоятельнее, чем прежде], (что я не могла понять), (что неприятного он мог видеть для меня в светской жизни).